# GPS Coordinates to Map Coordinates

Tags: navigation, mapping, gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to initialize my robot on a map through GPS for a navigation task. How can I convert GPS coordinates to map Coordinates?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

I am using the following launch files:

```
<launch>

    <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform_node" respawn="true">

      <param name="magnetic_declination_radians" value="0"/>

      <param name="roll_offset" value="0"/>

      <param name="pitch_offset" value="0"/>

      <param name="yaw_offset" value="0"/>

      <param name="zero_altitude" value="false"/>

      <remap from="/imu/data" to="/robot/imu" />
      <remap from="/gps/fix" to="/robot/gps" />

      <remap from="/odometry/gps" to="/initialpose" />

    </node>

</launch>
```

Launch file for ekf_localization_node

```
<!-- This node will take in measurements from odometry, IMU, stamped pose, and stamped twist messages. It tracks
     the state of the robot, with the state vector being defined as X position, Y position, Z position,
     roll, pitch, yaw, and the respective velocites for those quantities. Accelerations are not used (yet).
     Units for all measurements are assumed to be in meters and radians. By default, the node outputs an
     Odometry message with the topic name odometry/filtered -->
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization" clear_params="true">

  <!-- Set initial pose of the robot through code or rviz -->
  <remap from="set_pose" to="initialpose"/>

  <!-- The frequency, in Hz, at which the filter will output a position estimate. Note that
       the filter will not begin computation until it receives at least one message from
       one of the inputs. It will then run continuously at the frequency specified here,
       regardless of whether it receives more measurements. --> 
  <param name="frequency" value="30"/>  

  <!-- The period, in seconds, after which we consider a sensor to have timed out. In this event, we
       carry out a predict cycle on the EKF without correcting it. This parameter can be thought of
       as the minimum frequency with which the filter will generate output. -->
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.1"/>  

  <!-- The filter accepts an arbitrary number of inputs from each input message type (Odometry, PoseStamped,
       TwistStamped, Imu). To add a new one, simply append the next number in the sequence to its base name,
       e.g., odom0, odom1, twist0, twist1, imu0, imu1, imu2, etc. The value should be the topic name. -->
  <param name="odom0" value="robot/odom"/>
  <param name="imu0" value="robot/imu"/> 

  <!-- Each sensor reading updates some or all of the filter's state. These options give you greater control over
       which values from each measurement are fed to the filter. For example, if you have an odometry message as input,
       but only want to use its Z position value, then set the entire vector to false, except for the third entry.
       The order of the values is x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw. Note that not some message
       types lack certain variables. For example, a TwistWithCovarianceStamped message has no pose information, so the first
       six values would be meaningless in that case. -->
  <rosparam param="odom0_config">[false, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]</rosparam>
  <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, true, true, true]</rosparam>

  <!-- The best practice for including new sensors in ekf_localization_node is to pass in velocity measurements and let
       ekf_localization_node integrate them. However, this isn't always feasible, and so ekf_localization (and the other
       nodes in robot_localization) support fusion of absolute measurements. If you have more than one sensor providing
       absolute measurements, however, you will quickly run into problems, as the sensors will inevitably diverge from
       one another, causing the filter to jump back and forth rapidly. To combat this situation, you can set the sensor's
       differential parameter to true. This will carry out differential integration of the sensor data, i.e., it will 
       repeatedly integrate the difference between a given measurement and the previous measurement from that sensor. 
       NOTE: this only applies to sensors that provide absolute measurements, so Twist messages are not supported. -->
  <param name="odom0_differential" value="true"/>
  <param name="imu0_differential" value="true"/>

  <!-- Debug settings. Not for the faint of heart. Outputs a ludicrous amount of information to the file
       specified by debug_out_file. I hope you like matrices! -->
  <param name="debug"           value="false"/>
  <param name="debug_out_file"  value="debug_ekf_localization.txt"/>

  <!-- For the tf tree, this specifies the name of the local (odom) and vehicle (base_link) frames. There's 
       a good chance you can leave these alone, as the default values adhere to the ROS spec. -->
  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="robot/base_footprint"/>

  <!-- The process noise covariance matrix can be difficult to tune, and can vary for each application, so it
       is exposed as a configuration parameter. PLEASE NOTE that every value in this matrix *must* be specified
       as real-valued, i.e., it must have a decimal point. Integers don't load correctly. The values are ordered
       as x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, vx, vy, vz, vroll, vpitch, vyaw. -->
  <rosparam param="process_noise_covariance">[0.03, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.03, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.025, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.002, 0.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.002, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.004]</rosparam>

</node>
```

When I am running the move_base.launch (navigation stack), I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1416949561.233882834]: Client [/ekf_localization] wants topic /initialpose to have datatype/md5sum [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped/953b798c0f514ff060a53a3498ce6246], but our version has [nav_msgs/Odometry/cd5e73d190d741a2f92e81eda573aca7]. Dropping connection.
 [ERROR] [1416949561.248454412]: Client [/fake_localization] wants topic /initialpose to have datatype/md5sum [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped/953b798c0f514ff060a53a3498ce6246], but our version has [nav_msgs/Odometry/cd5e73d190d741a2f92e81eda573aca7]. Dropping connection.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198196/gps-coordinates-to-map-coordinates/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-11-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-11-25**:
What are map coordinates for you? What are GPS coordinates for you? What do you want to do? Might a TF link be a better choice?

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-25**:
I'm using the navigation stack, so I believe map is in the UTM frame and GPS is of type `sensor_msgs/NavSatFix` message (Not sure about the coordinate frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can `navsat_transform_node` a shot:

http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization#navsat_transform_node

It requires that you have a `sensor_msgs/NavSatFix` message with your GPS data in it, a `sensor_msgs/Imu` message with a global heading (e.g., from a magnetometer), and a `nav_msgs/Odometry` message with your vehicle's current position (as output by a state estimation node in [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization), or whatever you want to use). It will automatically transform all GPS data into your robot's world `frame_id`. The `frame_id` of the output `nav_msgs/Odometry` message will match the input `nav_msgs/Odometry` message `frame_id`. If you use the version that's currently in the [repo](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization), it will also publish the transform from your world `frame_id` to the UTM grid.

---

**EDIT for update 1:**

OK, for `ekf_localization_node`, I don't have your launch file, but your issue is almost certainly that you have this:

```
<param name="pose0" value="/initialpose"/>
```

...when you want this:

```
<param name="odom0" value="/initialpose"/>
```

If you specify a "poseN" parameter for `ekf_localization_node`, it assumes the type is `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped`. Since `navsat_transform_node` is outputting a `nav_msgs/Odometry` message, it's complaining.

You're having a similar issue with `amcl`, but I don't know if you can get `amcl` to listen to a `nav_msgs/Odometry` message instead of a `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped` message. You could always modify the `navsat_transform_node` source to output a `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped` message. It would be pretty straightforward.

Two more things:

1. Does your IMU read 0 at true north? You `navsat_transform_node` is configured that way right now.
2. Why are you feeding the GPS location to both amcl and `ekf_localization_node`? Again, I'm not very familiar with amcl.

It might be a good idea to post all of your launch files (`ekf_localization_node` and `amcl` as well).

---

**Edit after launch file posts:**

OK, I think there are quite a few things going on here.

First, you appear to be running `ekf_localization_node`, `amcl`, and `fake_localization`. As I understand it, both `amcl` and `fake_localization` provide the same information, so I'm thinking you really only need `amcl` (assuming you have a LIDAR and a map).

Second, let's consider your transforms. As you have it configured now, `ekf_localization_node` will provide a transform from *odom*->*robot/base_footprint*. If you do have a LIDAR and a map, then `amcl` will provide the *map*->*odom* transform, and you'll be in good shape. If you **do not** have a LIDAR and a map, then you have two options:

1. Use `fake_localization` to generate a *map*->*odom* transform.
2. Use a second instance of `ekf_localization_node` to generate the *map*->*odom* transform. Fuse the GPS data with that, and do not fuse it with the first instance that is providing the *odom*->*robot/base_link* transform.

Third - and this is critical - if you need to fuse the GPS data using `ekf_localization_node`, do **not** use the `set_pose` topic/service for feeding in the GPS data to `ekf_localization_node`. That is reserved for manually resetting the entire pose of the filter, and it's really designed to interact with things like `rviz`. It lets users reset out the state estimate without having to shut the node down and bring it back up. Instead, do this:

```
<param name="odom1" value="/initialpose"/>
<rosparam param="odom1">[true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]</rosparam>
<param name="odom1_differential" value="false"/>
```

I'm not sure what amcl expects, but I have a feeling you might want to double-check to make sure that you're using it correctly there as well.

Finally, your `ekf_localization_node` launch file is a bit out of date. If you're using the latest version (x.1.6 as of this writing), then see [this](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/indigo-devel/launch/ekf_template.launch) for an example. The most important changes are that the state now includes linear acceleration, so your boolean vectors need an extra 3 values (it's backwards-compatible, though). Also, you're using `amcl`, which I believe is 2D, so you can set the `two_d_mode` parameter to true.

EDIT for comments:

Sorry, I may have mistakenly said that the `set_pose` topic/service wants an `Odometry` message. It doesn't. It wants a `PoseWithCovarianceStamped` message, hence the incompatibility (the output of `navsat_transform_node` is an `Odometry` message).

However, I'm still not sure exactly what you mean by "I only want to initialize the robot on the map using the GPS." When the robot first starts, the *map* and *odom* frames should be (or can be) completely overlapping, i.e., with the same origin and orientation. In both coordinate frames, your robot should believe it's at position (0, 0) when it first starts. As the robot moves, its position in both frames will change. If you use `navsat_transform_node` and configure it correctly, the Odometry message will also start at (0, 0) and should be very close to your fused odometry data (without the GPS). They will eventually drift from one another as the odometry data accumulates error.

In any case, if you try to use the `set_pose` topic and tie it to the output of navsat_transform_node, it's literally going to continuously move the robot to the exact location of the GPS odometry message. You may as well not even use a filter.

I'm happy to continue this conversation here, but it's starting to get messy. :) I know this goes against the guidelines for this site, but maybe we can get you squared away offline (via e-mail, see my comment or the Github repo for my address), and then we'll update/clean this question.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-25**:
Thanks a lot Tom, This is what I needed. I'm using the launch file from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/GPS%20Integration) to run the node. The only issue is when I'm remapping `/odometry/gps` to `/initialpose`(Although they are of the same type `nav_msgs/Odometry`),

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-25**:
I get the error: [ERROR] [1416945303.777949700]: Client [/ekf_localization] wants topic /initialpose to have datatype/md5sum [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped/953b798c0f514ff060a53a3498ce6246], but our version has [nav_msgs/Odometry/cd5e73d190d741a2f92e81eda573aca7]. Dropping connection.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-25**:
Sorry, what is `ekf_localization`? Are you using `ekf_localization_node` (`robot_localization`) or `robot_pose_ekf`? If it's `ekf_localization_node`, you've got an issue in that launch file.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-25**:
...and that issue is likely that you have "initialpose" included as "pose0" intead of "odom0." Pose messages assume the PoseWithCovarianceStamped type. Odometry messages assume the Odometry type.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-25**:
I am using `ekf_localization_node (robot_localization)`, updated my question

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-25**:
In fact I am not setting any `pose0` for my `ekf_localization_node`

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-25**:
I noticed. Answer forthcoming...

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-25**:
Sorry, that `amcl` was a mistake. I'm not using `amcl`. I'm only using `fake_localization`. `fake_localization` generates the map->odom transform and `ekf_lozalization` generates the odom->robot/base_footprint transform. I updated the error messages (`amcl` is not complainig anymore)

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-25**:
Regarding your third point, I didn't intend to fuse the GPS data along with odometry and imu using `ekf_localization_node`, and as it is shown in my `ekf_template.launch` file I haven't included the GPS. I only want to initialize the robot on the map using the GPS

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-25**:
@Tom Moore, I couldn't figure out how to private message you on here

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-11-27**:
@Tom Moore, Tom can you please have a look at here ?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-27**:
Use email: tmoore at cra dot com